# Java application auto fill username and password

Tags: java, swing, automation

I have a Swing base Java application that requires ldap user and password for login. I would like to automate the login so that each time the application is launched, it fills the user and password.
I have seen library robot for java but could not make it.
Is there a way to pass through the JVM / or read Swing component in JVM?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to add the remember me feature If you use a database like SQL or oracle then keep the checkbox option in the database with boolean. Otherwise, the checkbox is selected then store your password in some hidden file on the user path. Next time before login look at that password.

Sample code

```
   String file_path=System.getProperty("user.home")+"/.myapp";
    FileWriter obj=new FileWriter(file_path);
    obj.write("Your Password Here ");
    obj.close();
```

Comment: I think I was not clear enough with my question. I do not have the source code of the application. 
I would like if possible to get the xpath of the swing components (for ex: Textfield ... ) to fill its content. 
Maybe from JVM loaded classes ?